# How to get lightning combobox list appear on top when there is few rows in lightning Datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, custom, lightning-combobox, column

My question is similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246730/can-we-specify-a-minimum-height-for-a-lightningdatatable-lightning-datatable), I have a custom dropdown column which is appearing completely fine when we have many rows in the datatable. But in a sitation when we have a single record, it
Lightning:datatable custom dropdown list items seem to be appearing behind the LWC datatable's container.

[image]

I tried setting min-height, but it did not resolve the issue.

Also tried overriding below,

```
.slds-dropdown_left, .slds-dropdown--left {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Didn't help though.
Any helpful suggestions to get this dropdown list appear without having to scroll this tiny row.
Thank you!

Comment: This is a known issue because the combobox only has a look-n-feel like dropdown. You might want to replace it with a native select element. You would need to add logic for the selected value. And incase you still want to use the combobox i guess the solution is to set overflow to visible from a static resource. However it still might have few other issues.

Comment: Thank you @SachinHooda, it worked according to your suggestion. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @SachinHooda's suggestion in comment, Replaced lwc combobox with with  and that fixed the issue.

```
    <div class="slds-select_container" >
        <select name="peGroup"  value={selectedId} class="slds-select" onchange={handleChange}>
            <template for:each={options} for:item="opt">
               <option key={opt.value} value={opt.value}>{opt.label}</option> 
            </template>
        </select>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can mark it as solved. :)